# Trigger adds a value with sequence CAN`T solve

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I`m trying to solve a trigger issue. So I have to replace the value for every inserted row with new value from the sequence DEPARTMENTS_SEQ. And I ended up here

```
create or replace TRIGGER hr_insert_tr on DEPARTMENTS
    BEFORE INSERT on DEPARTMENTS 
    for each ROW 

BEGIN
    DEPARTMENT_ID = :new.DEPARTMENTS_SEQ;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be

```
create or replace trigger hr_insert_tr
  before insert on departments
  for each row
begin
  :new.department_id := departments_seq.nextval;
end;
/
```

Comment: Hey, thantks for the solution. Is there any chance can you explain to me why :new and .nextval

Comment: You're welcome. `:new.` represents a pseudorecord; it is used to reference a "new" value you're inserting into a table. Just for information, there's also the `:old.` pseudorecord used to reference "previous" ("old") value - it is used when you UPDATE a row so you can e.g. compare `if :new.name <> :old.name then ...`. As of the sequence: that's how you reference it, by specifying its name (`departments_seq` and its next value - `nextval`; if the last value fetched from sequence was 100, NEXTVAL would return 101 (OK, that depends on how you created it, but - generally speaking - that's it).

Comment: well, that make sense. I`ve read the Oracle documentation for the Triggers and Sequence and haven`t seen to mention "nextval".... :(

Comment: For some more info, have a look here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-sequences#usage-in-sql-and-plsql and here: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-sequence/oracle-create-sequence/